# Member of type multiple interfaces

Tags: .net, oop

I am trying to declare a Property (or Function for that matter) of a type that satisfies several interfaces. I'm assuming this can't be done in C# or VB. My question is, if it makes sense to define a type that implements multiple interfaces, why cant you define a member of such?
Ex.
I can do this

```
interface IBar
{ String BarMember; }

interface IFoo
{ String FooMember; }

class FooBar : IBar, IFoo
{ 
    public string BarMember{get;set;}
    public string FooMember{get;set;}
}
```

so why cant i do this

```
class SomeClass
{
    public {IBar, IFoo} FooBarMember {get;set;}
}
```

in this case FooBar would satisfy SomeClass.FooBarMember?

The reason I need this is simply that i need a member that satisfies those interface requirements. I dont care what the actual concrete class is.
I know i can combine both of the interfaces by creating a new interface that combines both of them, but why should i have to do that?

Comment: This code isn't compilable.  You might want to edit "BarMember" and "FooMember" to be automatically implemented properties: "{String BarMember { get; set; }"

Answer (score 2):

OK, now that I finally understood the question: generics to the rescue!

```
class SomeClass<T> where T : IFoo, IBar
{
    public T FooBarMember { get; set; } 
}
```

Now, `FooBarMember` will be of type `T`, which is a type that must implement both `IFoo` and `IBar`.

Consider this:

```
class A : IBar
{
    public string SomeMember { get; set; }
}

class B : IFoo
{
    public string SomeMember { get; set; }
}

class C : IFoo, IBar
{
    public string SomeMember { get; set; }
}
```

Three classes, `A` implements `IBar`, `B` implements `IFoo` and `C` implements both. Now, take the following code:

```
SomeClass<A> aa = new SomeClass<A>();  // doesn't compile
SomeClass<B> bb = new SomeClass<B>();  // doesn't compile
SomeClass<C> cc = new SomeClass<C>();  // works fine
```

This means that we can do like so:

```
SomeClass<C> cc = new SomeClass<C>();
cc.FooBarMember = new C();
```

Comment: no, you can't do" public {IBar, IFoo} FooBarMember {get;set;} . thats my point. And read the question please: I have a solution, I want to know why IN DESIGN I cant do what I want.

Comment: I'm not trying to say FooBarMember is a string but rather FooBarMember is a FooBar object (which implements both IFoo and IBar)

Comment: @Fragilerus: Ah.. now I get it (not too fast today, admittedly). Hmm... (thinking)

Comment: @Fragilerus: there, now I hope we nailed it :)

Comment: this is a bit confusing. what nailed it?

Comment: @Fragilerus: check updated answer :) Hope it's understandable, otherwise I'll elaborate later (need to leave the computer for a couple of hours).

Comment: Thats very sharp! I actually got the idea of being able to declare a member that imeplements multiple interfaces from generics (the {IFoo, IBar} notation is VB). Yes, we're finally on the same page. My question is, why should I have to deligate it to generics and not do it directly? It so happens, I don't like using generics. .net 3.5 (no covarience and contravarience) and XAML (no support at all) are not very kind to it. I want to know why in design this is not allowed.

Comment: @Fragilerus: I can only speculate, but I assume that it simply does not solve a problem that is big and common enough to defend the cost of implementing the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're asking the compiler to do:

You're saying "This function returns an IBar or an IFoo."  The compiler *needs* to know which because they have different interfaces.  If you don't pick a specific one then it can't determine whether calls you make on the return value of that function are legitimate.

Tell me, given your code, is the following legal? (The answer is "who the heck knows"):

```
someClass.FooBarMember.FooMember;
```

The reason you can declare a type that implements both is that the compiler knows that you have both "FooMember" and "BarMember" declared in it, so adding:

```
IFooBar : IFoo, IBar{ <...> }
```

Means that any `IFooBar` you declare can resolve calls to FooMember and BarMember correctly at compile time.

C# is *not* an interpreted language.

Comment: no, you are missunderstanding. I want to declare a member that implements BOTH interfaces. let me try to explain it a little better. i can say IFooBar : IFoo, IBar and then say class Someclass{ IFooBar FooBarMember; }. Why not say class Someclass{ {IFoo,IBar} FooBarMember;}? how is that not the same thing? {IFoo,IBar} means it implements BOTH.

Comment: Oh, you want it to create an anonymous type?

Comment: What would the Type of the return value of such a member be?

Comment: no, not an anonymous type (i know this is not java where you can have anonymous types implement interfaces). The type of the return would be any type that implements those interfaces.

Comment: CPfohl: happened to edit the wrong answer... (rolled it back; sorry for the inconvenience) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can implementing multiple interfaces on a method using generics as follows:

```
     public void SetMultipleInterfaceObject<T>(T item) 
     where T : IInterface1, IInterface2 {
        _multipleInterfaceObject = item;
     }
```

You can store the multiple interface object as follows. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this. If there is, I haven't found it yet:

```
     private object _multipleInterfaceObject;
     public IInterface1? Interface1Object => (IInterface1) _compositeInterfaceObject;
     public IInterface2? Interface2Object => (IInterface2) _compositeInterfaceObject;
```